# Windows 11 and Docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path (file exists)

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, volumes

If I try

```
PS C:\Users\me\docker_apps\app> docker run -v /Users/me/docker_volumes/etc:/etc/todos -dp 3000:3000 my_app
```

The docker returns:

```
enter code here`docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/Users/me/docker_volumes/etc': mkdir /Users: file exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows requires to use the drive letter, so instead of

```
/Users/me/docker_volumes/etc:/etc/todos
```

It is important to use

```
C:/Users/me/docker_volumes/etc:/etc/todos
```

So this one works:

```
PS C:\Users\me\docker_apps\app> docker run -v C:/Users/me/docker_volumes/etc:/etc/todos -dp 3000:3000 my_app
```